# How to change month format for ls -l custom command

Tags: c, stat, localtime

When you make this command :

```
find ok/ -exec ls -l -d {} \;
```

The terminal displays :

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 alexia alexia 4096 8 oct.  15 22:31 ok/
```

I tried to make my own find command to do the same thing with stat.h :

```
[...] //Other file information
struct stat fileStat;
stat(path,&fileStat)
char buffer[20];
struct tm *time
time = localtime(&(fileStat.st_mtime));
strftime(buffer, 20, "%b %e  %Y", time);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

and it displays:

```
[...]
8 Oct  15 22:31 ok/
```

The month format is not good, and I do no know how to get it right.

Cheers

Comment: Have you set the locale? By default, it works in the C locale.  Perhaps `setlocale(LC_TIME, “”);`?  Failing that, you can add the dot to the format string, but that won’t fix the case of the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, C programs run with the C locale.  It looks as though you want a different locale, so use the [`setlocale()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) function with another locale.  The simplest is specified by the empty string. (*A value of "C" for locale specifies the minimal environment for C translation; a value of "" for locale specifies the locale-specific native environment. Other implementation-defined strings may be passed as the second argument to setlocale.*):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, “”);
```

This only affects time; you could use `LC_ALL` to change everything.